# Precompile json data and include with Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to precompile and use [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) with Ruby on Rails on Heroku.

Here is the JavaScript console error I am getting when I compile the `bootstrap-toggle.min.js.map` file that also comes with the `css` and `js` files,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
application-4df1877ce16cb310440b73a84d39fd58.js:14555
```

And the error line is a long `json` object that basically looks like,

```
{"version":3,"file":"bootstrap-toggle.min.js", ... }
```

Why am I getting this JavaScript error?

And also, should I have this line in my `application.js` file?

```
//= require bootstrap-toggle.min.js.map
```

**UPDATE:**
If someone does want to look into why I can't precompile `json` with getting JavaScript console errors that is great. I found a work around by not precompiling the `json` at all at including it in my `public/assets` folder. I updated the linked to that folder.

Comment: Try just putting the individual `.min.js` and `.min.css` files in `../assets/javascripts` and `../assets/stylesheets` respectively and making sure that you have `//= require tree` in `application.js` and `application.css`

Comment: I removed the `json` file as you suggested, and another `json` file gave me the same error. It appears that this is an error with precompling `json` data.

Comment: I renamed and editted the post to reflect that it is a `json` problem in general.

Comment: Based on the error I would think you would need to escape the quotes in the json - just a guess.